# Batch class run in real time through custom button instead of going to anonymous window in Developer console

Tags: visualforce, batch, custom-button, class

We have tool for mass lead conversion in salesforce. We have used lead rule custom object. We can schedule this conversion but has to go to developer console and had to run

```
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new leadConversionBatchable(), 200); '
```

Instead of doing this, i was trying to build custom button with VF page and in controller trying to handle multiple records which is apparently not working.

Do you guys have any other suggestions?? Is this possible in salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch classes can absolutely be enqueued in Apex code. A Visualforce action function can execute the very same code you're using in the Developer Console:

```
public PageReference runBatch() {
    Database.executeBatch(new leadConversionBatchable(), 200); 
    return null;
}
```

Your `<apex:commandButton>` can then execute this function. You can add functionality to show a message to the user or poll the batch status if needed, assigning the batch ID to an instance variable.

Note however that batch classes can also implement the `Schedulable` interface, which would allow you to execute the batch on a regular basis without human intervention.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time @David Reed! Highly Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The Non Profit Success Pack built by Salesforce.Org has done some really nice work around running batches from the UI so folks can run them manually - the code live in this github repo - take a look here for the UI around progress indicators
https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/master/src/components/UTIL_JobProgressLightning.component

and here for some of the code that queries the jobs in progress and display the progress:
https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/master/src/classes/UTIL_JobProgress_CTRL.cls